# Как определить несколько RadioListTitle в горизонтальном порядке?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

я столкнулся с проблемой, у меня есть 2 RadioListTitle, они расположены по вертикали, а  мне необходимо расположить их по горизонтали. Как это сделать?
Текст программы:

```
RadioListTile(
        title: const Text('Мужской'),
        value: GenderList.male,
        groupValue: _gender,
        onChanged: (GenderList value) {setState(() { _gender = value;});},
      ),

       RadioListTile(
        title: const Text('Женский'),
        value: GenderList.female,
        groupValue: _gender,
        onChanged: (GenderList value) {setState(() { _gender = value;});},
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Поместить в  Row and Expanded

```
Row(
 children:[
  Expanded(child: RadioListTile(...) ),
  Expanded(child: RadioListTile(...) ),
 ],
)
```